# Use Lodash to find the indexOf a JSON array inside of an [] array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, lodash, vuejs2

I have an array that looks something like this.

```
Users : {
  0 : { BidderBadge: "somestuff", Bidders: 6, }
  1 : { BidderBadge: "somemorestuff", Bidders: 7,}
}
```

I want to search the array using lodash to find a value inside of each of the user objects.

Specifically, I want to use values from another similar array of objects to find the value.

```
var bidArray = [];
    _.each(this.vue.AllUsers, function(user) {
      _.each(this.vue.Bids, function(bid) {
        if(user.BidderBadge == bid.Badge) {   
          bidArray.push(user);
        }
      });
    });
```

This is what I have and it works, but I want to do it using only one loop instead of two. I want to use something like _.indexOf. Is that possible?

Comment: `bidArray = thus.vue.AllUsers.filter(user => this.vue.Bids.some(bid => user.BidderBadge == bid.Badge));`

Comment: @Azamantes: Nice code. It's certainly simpler, but note that it is still two nested loops. (`filter` and `some` each run a loop.) Michael: Is your purpose in wanting only a single loop just to have simpler code, or to avoid the performance impact of the nested loops if these arrays are very long?

Comment: You can always make it faster by caching the arrow function, looping first over the smaller array or just do a `while` loop. I don't see a solution with just 1 loop here, I'll give a plus if someone proves me wrong.

Comment: @MichaelCoder: Also note that the `Users` object shown at the beginning of your question is not an array, but an object with numeric keys. It isn't even an "array-like" object because it lacks a `length` property. Is this an accurate representation of what you're working with, or are `AllUsers` and `Bids` actual arrays?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is difficult to give an accurate answer with an example that doesn't coincide with the input that your provide.

Anyway, supposing your data structures were more or less like this ones, you could solve the problem with lodash [_.intersectionWith](https://lodash.com/docs/4.16.4#intersectionWith).

Intersect both arrays using a comparator that checks the correct object properties. Also, take into account that users must go first in the intersection due to the fact that you're interested in its values.

```
function comparator(user, bid) {
  return user.BidderBadge === bid.Badge;
}
console.log(_.intersectionWith(users, bids, comparator));
```

Here's the [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/mnamwpmo/).

Comment: Thank you. That is a great example. I would up-vote this, but unfortunately I don't have enough points to do so. Feel free to up-vote my question and I will up-vote this whenever I get enough reputation to do so.

Comment: I ended up using _.find, but I will try this example in the future. It seems much easier this way.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to avoid nesting, you just have to modify Azamantes' solution a bit

```
var bidders = this.vue.Bids.reduce(function(acc, bid) {
    return acc[bid.BidderBadge] = true;
}, {});
var bidArray = this.vue.AllBidders.filter(function(bidder) {
    return !!bidders[bidder.Badge];
});
```

Comment: Thank you. That is a great example. I would up-vote this, but unfortunately I don't have enough points to do so. Feel free to up-vote my question and I will up-vote this whenever I get enough reputation to do so.

Comment: I would have put this as the answer, it is a very good example, but I'm using the example below.

Comment: @MichaelCoder that actually is a pretty good answer, but I bet it's slower ;)

Comment: I'll have to keep that in mind. If it does end up being more efficient I will change it.